# Tomcat High CPU usage and OutOfMemory issue

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

**Application Stack:**

- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
- JDK 1.8.0_201
- Spring Boot: 2.6.6
- Oracle 12c
- Tomcat 8.5.31

After I have added a batch (runs every 6 hours) which creates 6 excel files (max file size: 12MB) from DB, There was a surge in high CPU usage during this batch execution. Then after few days the CPU usage **didn't fall back to normal** 5-10% cpu usage level. It **gradually increased** then in turn lead to **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**. I optimized the code still same issue occurred but it took few days more.

Below image shows CPU Usage(%).

[image: CPU Usage (%)]

I'm unable to reproduce this issue in my local or in any other server. Can anyone suggest what could be the possible issue.

```
/**
* Used to cache few tables using CompletableFuture.
*/
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(25);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-thread-");
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}


/**
 * 
 * Configures the scheduler to allow multiple concurrent pools.
 * Used for Batches
 */
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer
{  
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar)
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(25);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("task-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }    
}
```

Excel Batch

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class ExceltReportBatchProcessor {
...

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/6 * * *", zone = "UTC")
    public void printMessage() {
            JobParameters statusJobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .toJobParameters();
            jobLauncher.run(excelReportNotify(), statusJobParameters);
    }
}
```

**Also when I stop the tomcat service it gives below warning/error in catalina.ot**

```
WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [excel-app] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:327)
07-Jan-2023 03:02:27.855 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [excel-app] appears to have started a thread named [task-pool-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
07-Jan-2023 03:02:27.860 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [excel-app] appears to have started a thread named [task-pool-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
...
...

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa3008b800 nid=0x1876 in Object.wait() [0x00007fa9fa9a6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000000c0044f40> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa30082000 nid=0x1875 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa30021800 nid=0x186d runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa30023800 nid=0x186e runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa30025000 nid=0x186f runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa30027000 nid=0x1870 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa30028800 nid=0x1871 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa3002a800 nid=0x1872 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa3002c000 nid=0x1873 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa3002e000 nid=0x1874 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007faa300d2000 nid=0x187e waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 2470

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 328192K, used 295629K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ffd00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 312320K, 94% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000fcba3790,0x00000000fdc00000)
  from space 15872K, 0% used [0x00000000fed80000,0x00000000fed90000,0x00000000ffd00000)
  to   space 16896K, 0% used [0x00000000fdc00000,0x00000000fdc00000,0x00000000fec80000)
 ParOldGen       total 427520K, used 169725K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000da180000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 427520K, 39% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000ca5bf630,0x00000000da180000)
 Metaspace       used 119147K, capacity 124996K, committed 125132K, reserved 1159168K
  class space    used 14369K, capacity 15321K, committed 15360K, reserved 1048576K
```

From Local SpringBoot application Excel batch running on every 5 min
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code of the job itself? Probably each job run is holding references to some objects, which prevents the GC from releasing memory.

Comment: Sorry I can't share the code, code base is large. Can you please mention how can I debug/troubleshoot this ? I have VisualVM to test in local, But don't know the parameters/properties to be taken count of.

Comment: You don't need to share _everything_: A [mcve] is enough (and what we actually prefer), and its creation might already help you identifying where you hold on to memory references that should have been released.

Comment: May be you are not releasing file handlers for each excel file. As a simple test if the OS is Linux, list the xsl files opened by the process with `lsof -p <PID> | grep '.*\.xsl' | wc -l`. The count could increase by 6 on each job run.